# Open file from path relative to the system root python

Tags: python

Is there a way to use the Open() function with an absolute path? I would like to open any file wherever it is on the disk, but Open() sets it's working directory to the location of the file by default, can I change this?

Comment: What `Open()` function are you talking about?  Do you mean the standard `open()` function?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo

Comment: As long as you pass an absolute path to `open()`, the working directory is irrelevant.  It is only used to turn a provided relative path into an absolute path.

Comment: Sorry, I was assigning the file path with a variable through a function call, when I surrounded it by an str(), for some reason it worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux you would need to add a `/` to the beginning of the path, for example to access `/tmp/someFile.txt` you would do `open("/tmp/someFile.Txt")`. This works because / references the root.

On windows (this has not been tested) i before you would do `open("C:/someFile.txt")`.

The docs for the open function can be found at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open